# Error while trying to run protractor test on chrome

Tags: protractor, webdriver-manager

When I run the protractor test on the machine I get the following error:

> Failed: invalid argument
>         (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.87)
>         (Driver info: chromedriver=80.0.3987.16 (320f6526c1632ad4f205ebce69b99a062ed78647-refs/branch-heads/3987@{#185}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.18362 x86_64)

When I try to run `webdriver-manager update`, I am only getting the `chromedriver=80.0.3987.16` version, not the new one `chrome=80.0.3987.87`.

Comment: Can you please post more information like your configuration file and the entire error stack?

Comment: If you want to run tests on newer version, you can download it manually and place it in the folder {Your Project}\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run tests on newer version, you can download it manually and place it in the folder

```
{Your Project}\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium
```